# Split every row containing long text into multiple rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which has a string column such as below:

```
id                         text                      label
1            this is long string with many words       1
2                 this is a middle string              0
3                      short string                    1
```

and i want to convert this DataFrame to another DataFrame based on the string length i.e. (`df['text'].str.len > 3`) :

```
id                         text                      label
1                      this is long                    1
1                    string with many                  1
1                         words                        1
2                       this is a                      0
2                     middle string                    0
3                     short string                     1
```

this is my code:

```
pd.concat(df['text'].str.len() > 200)
```

but it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

```
In [1257]: n = 3

In [1279]: df.set_index(['label', 'id'])['text'].str.split().apply(
               lambda x: pd.Series([' '.join(x[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(x), n)])
            ).stack().reset_index().drop('level_2', 1)
Out[1279]:
   label  id                 0
0      1   1      this is long
1      1   1  string with many
2      1   1             words
3      0   2         this is a
4      0   2     middle string
5      1   3      short string
```

---

Details

```
   label                                 text  id
0      1  this is long string with many words   1
1      0              this is a middle string   2
2      1                         short string   3
```

Comment: thanks @Zero, but your code doesn't include id column.

Comment: drops this error : ValueError: labels ['level_2'] not contained in axis

Comment: when i use text column, it shows  " KeyError: 'text' "

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
v=df.text.str.split(' ')

s=pd.DataFrame({'text':v.sum(),'label':df.label.repeat(v.str.len())})

s['New']=s.groupby(s.index).cumcount()

s.groupby([s.New//3,s.index.get_level_values(level=0)]).agg({'text':lambda x : ' '.join(x),'label':'first'}).sort_index(level=1)

Out[1785]: 
                   text  label
New                           
0   0      this is long      1
1   0  string with many      1
2   0             words      1
0   1         this is a      0
1   1     middle string      0
0   2      short string      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution, using a couple of for loops to split your text into sets of 3:

```
array = []
for ii,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['text'].split() > 3:
        jj = 0
        while jj < len(row['text'].split()):
            array.append(
                pd.Series(
                {'id':row['id'],'label':row['label'],
                'text':row['text'].split()[jj:jj+3]}
                ) 
            )
            jj += 3
    else:
        array.append(row)
```